# Color around the Text in HTML

Tags: html, css, text, border

I needed to show color around the text in my HTML page, I tried border property but it is giving square box around the Text.
How to achieve below requirement

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would write the code here... But this link http://line25.com/articles/using-css-text-shadow-to-create-cool-text-effects explains it so well.

**Example Demo** : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CDsFb

This is actually much better ...

```
text-shadow: 3px 3px 0 #000,
    /* Simulated effect for Firefox and Opera and nice enhancement for WebKit */
   -3px -3px 0 #000,  
    3px -3px 0 #000,
   -3px  3px 0 #000,
    3px  3px 0 #000;
```

This will ensure it **looks like a proper border** you want and not a simple glow around your text.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `text-shadow` CSS property

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px orange;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NGPhL/

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textshadow.html

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #1d1dab;
filter: dropshadow(color=#1d1dab, offx=0, offy=0);
```

http://css3generator.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CSS3 text-shadow property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp). As long the browser supports webkit, this should surfice.

Answer (score 0):

If browser don't support CSS3:

Use can use two text nodes with 17px and 18px font-size (for example) and positioning by CSS first under second (position:absolute, z-index:100, left, top, etc) with different colors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks For your suggestions, I found an example to get this requirement here

http://gazpo.com/2011/02/text-shadow/
7. Border Around the text

```
text-shadow: 0 -4px #00468C,4px 0 #00468C,0 4px #00468C,-4px 0 #00468C,4px -4px #00468C,-4px 4px #00468C,4px 4px #00468C,-4px -4px #00468C;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main-heading h2{

    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #42a6e1;
}
```

The text-shadow not working fine. So use text stroke instead of text-shadow. Text shadow also makes difficulties at different devices.

You can see in the screenshot given below
[image: You can see in the screenshot given below]